# How to create key binding to set XML syntax?

Tags: key-bindings, sublimetext2

I'd like to switch to XML syntax in Sublime Text 2 using some key binding, for example **Ctrl+Shift+X**.
There is a command for that, I can successfully execute it from console:

```
view.set_syntax_file("Packages/XML/XML.tmLanguage")
```

I tried this binding, but it doesn't work:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+x"], "command": "set_syntax_file", "args" : {"syntax_file" : "Packages/XML/XML.tmLanguage" }}
```

[Here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html#sublime.View) API reference for the **set_syntax_file** command can be found.
Any ideas?

Comment: For one-time-commands like that, you may prefer to use the quick menu. I think the default binding is Ctrl+Shift+P; enter "XML", hit Enter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+x"], "command": "set_file_type", "args" : {"syntax" : "Packages/XML/XML.tmLanguage" } }
```

Comment: Works! I have already created a small plugin that uses API. How did you come with that solution?

Comment: @Werolik Open the console and run "sublime.log_commands(1)" to log all commands. Then use ST2 as normal and see what commands are being executed in each action

Comment: Thanks a lot! That makes life a lot easier. And I really like ST2 more and more ;)

Answer (score 0):

set_syntax_file is an API command, so to use it I created a simple plug-in.